# Where do I import linkage from in numba-scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, numba

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage, cut_tree
>>> "WHAT TO PUT HERE"   from numba_scipy.special.overloads import linkage "?"


X = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0],
     [1.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0],
     [1.0,2.0,5.0,6.0,7.0],
     [2.0,3.0,5.0,4.0,3.0]]

Xdf = pd.DataFrame(data=X).transpose()

Zf = linkage(Xdf.transpose(), 'single', 'correlation')
```

I want to change this to use numba-scipy, but there is no documentation (Yes there is a site but there is no actual documentation).

What do I need to put on the import line?

Comment: This package [documentation](https://numba-scipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/index.html) is a joke. It looks like experimental module and it may not be meant to be directly used. The [numba_scipy.special](https://numba-scipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/special.html#) part has no `overloads`/`linkage` function/sub-package (nor any `correlation` function). What makes you think it is supported?

Comment: I saw this:

https://github.com/hgrecco/scipy_numba/blob/master/scipy_numba/cluster/hierarchy.py

And was hoping it was now offical part of numba